# Assigning an executable function to a property of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, function

** JS Snippet **

```
$.getJSON('json/json.getJob.php', {job_id: job_id}, function(jsonJobData)
    {
        job.data = jsonJobData;
        $.each(job.data, function(k, v)
            {
                placeDataToID(k,v);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

As you can see in my snippet, I am creating an object called `job`. I'm filling the `data` property of `job` with the results of a PHP JsonSerializable call. Then I would like to create another property called `display` that holds the `$.each` iteration function you see above.

I know it's possible, and I thought I was close when I used:

```
job = {
    display: function() {
        $.each(job.data, function(k,v) {
            placeDataToID(k,v);
        });
    }
};
```

but when I called it using `job.call(display);` I was surprised to see that *display was undefined*. Could someone with a stronger JS background give me a hand with this?

Comment: You never made a `call` function in `job`.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem, but apparently as SLaks answered, `job.display()` should do it.

Comment: Is there a problem with using `job.data` within the function?

Comment: Technically no as long as you set it before calling the function, but obviously there are better ways to pass your response object to your iterative function (as an argument, for example).

Comment: [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a method on functions that you use to call a function with a specific `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display` is a property of `job`, just like any other property.
You access it by writing `job.display`.

Comment: Just that easy.. `job.display()` works like a champ! Thank you!